# Binary Symmetric Channel calculating problem(the answer of two method should be the same,however,its not )

Tags: probability

This is a Binary Symmetric Channel ,now Let $P(X)=(p,1-p)$ where $0 \le p \le 1$,and $X=Y=(0,1)$

$P(X|Y)=$
\begin{bmatrix}
1-\epsilon & \epsilon\\
\epsilon & 1-\epsilon
\end{bmatrix}
and $0\le  \epsilon \le 1 , P_e=Pr[X \neq Y]$,

$ X \neq Y $ means $X=0,Y=1$ or $X=1,Y=0$,and we have two methods to calculate it.One is $P_e=Pr[X=0,Y=1]+Pr[X=1,Y=0]$ , the other is $P_e=1-[Pr[X=1,Y=1]+Pr[X=0,Y=0]]$ . Theoretically,their answer should be the same.However,my answer is not the same,so i think i must have a mistake in somewhere,hoping someone can tell me

$P_e=Pr[X=0,Y=1]+Pr[X=1,Y=0]=\epsilon+\epsilon=2\epsilon$

$P_e=1-[Pr[X=1,Y=1]+Pr[X=0,Y=0]]=1-[(1-\epsilon)+(1-\epsilon)]=1-2+2\epsilon=-1+2\epsilon$

Where am i wrong?

Comment: First mistake: $\Pr[X=0,Y=1]\ne\epsilon$, actually, $$\Pr[X=0,Y=1]=\Pr[X=0]\Pr[Y=1\mid X=0]$$ with probably $\Pr[X=0]=1-p$ and $\\Pr[Y=1\mid X=0]=\epsilon$ (except that you mangled the notations big time).

Comment: If you add the entries of the matrix then you get $2$ so they cannot correspond with probabilities of mutually exclusive events. Most probably the entries are conditional probabilities.